# Динамическое обновление RecyclerView с вложенной структурой (Parent -> Child)

Tags: android, recyclerview, update, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть список содержащий вложенную структуру с отношением Parent и Child. Он отображает список групп, к каждой группе находится вложенный список с лампами. Вот так выглядит экран со списком.

[image: Внешний вид]

**Проблема**

Возникла необходимость сделать динамическое обновление всего списка. К сожалению я встал в тупик и не могу ничего придумать. Сам список должен обновляться без перерисовки их элементов а только содержимого в следующих случаях:

1. Когда происходит подключение к группе устройств. Если нажимаем на Connect и хотя бы одно устройство будет подключено, то TextView со словом Connect исчезнет и появится кнопка с включением (как на элементе вложенного списка). Соответственно если все устройства вдруг потеряют связь то снова будет показан TextView со словом Connect
2. При обновлении состояния включена лампа или выключена. Значок выключения должен изменить цвет на зеленый (лампа включена) и серый (лампа выключена)
3. Изменился заряд батареи у лампы.

Ниже приведу реализацию своего адаптера с вложенным списком.

***GroupSaberAdapter.kt***

````
    private val itemList: MutableList<Item> = ArrayList()
    private var callback: GroupSabersAdapterCallback? = null

    fun addCallback(callback: GroupSabersAdapterCallback) {
        this.callback = callback
    }

    fun updateItemList(newItemList: ArrayList<Item>) {
        itemList.clear()
        itemList.addAll(newItemList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun setConnectionState(connectedDevices: Map<BluetoothDevice, Boolean>) {
        // ..как то обновить список при изменении состояния подключения
        // Boolean true если подключено
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = itemList.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return itemList[position].getItemType()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            Item.CHILD -> ChildViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_saber_view, false))
            else -> ParentViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_group_view, false))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder.itemViewType) {
            Item.CHILD -> {
                val childViewHolder = holder as ChildViewHolder
                childViewHolder.childItem = itemList[position] as ChildItem
                childViewHolder.bind()
            }
            else -> {
                val parentViewHolder = holder as ParentViewHolder
                parentViewHolder.parentItem = itemList[position] as ParentItem
                parentViewHolder.bind()
            }
        }
    }

    inner class ParentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        lateinit var parentItem: ParentItem

        private val textGroupName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textGroupName)
        private val textDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDescription)
        private val imageArrowExpanded: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageExpanded)
        private val buttonExpanded: ViewGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonExpanded)
        private val textConnect: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textConnect)
        private val containerControlGroup: LinearLayout =
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.containerControlGroup)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                callback?.onItemClick(parentItem.childItems.map { childItem -> childItem.saber })
            }
            textConnect.setOnClickListener {
                callback?.onConnectClick(parentItem.childItems.map { childItem -> childItem.saber })
            }
            buttonExpanded.setOnClickListener {
                val startPosition = adapterPosition + 1
                val count = parentItem.childItems.size

                if (parentItem.isExpanded) {
                    itemList.removeAll(parentItem.childItems)
                    notifyItemRangeRemoved(startPosition, count)
                    parentItem.isExpanded = false
                } else {
                    itemList.addAll(startPosition, parentItem.childItems)
                    notifyItemRangeInserted(startPosition, count)
                    parentItem.isExpanded = true
                }
                updateExpandedViewState()
            }

        }

        fun bind() {
            updateExpandedViewState()
            textGroupName.text = parentItem.title
            if (parentItem.childItems.size > 0) {
                val type = parentItem.childItems[0].saber.type.toTypeString()
                textDescription.text =
                    String.format("%d sabers - %s", parentItem.childItems.size, type)
                if (parentItem.connected) {
                    containerControlGroup.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textConnect.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                } else {
                    containerControlGroup.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    textConnect.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                return
            }
            textDescription.text = String.format("%d sabers", parentItem.childItems.size)
        }

        private fun updateExpandedViewState() {
            if (parentItem.isExpanded) {
                imageArrowExpanded.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_up_arrow)
            } else {
                imageArrowExpanded.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_down_arrow)
            }
        }
    }

    inner class ChildViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        lateinit var childItem: ChildItem

        private val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDeviceName)

        fun bind() {
            title.text = childItem.saber.name
        }
    }
}


// Item.kt Базовый Item

interface Item {

    fun getItemType(): Int

    companion object {
        const val PARENT = 1
        const val CHILD = 2
    }
}




// ParentItem.kt Item родитель (отображение группы)

data class ParentItem(val id: Long, val title: String) : Item {
    val childItems = ArrayList<ChildItem>()
    var isExpanded = false
    var connected = false
    var selectedChild: ChildItem? = null

    override fun getItemType(): Int = Item.PARENT
}





// ChildItem.kt Item ребенок (отображение ламп)

data class ChildItem(
    val parent: ParentItem,
    val id: Long,
    val saber: Saber
): Item {
    override fun getItemType(): Int = Item.CHILD
}```


Как можно динамически обновлять список при поступлении новых данных? Надеюсь на вашу помощь.
````